# How can I show the Search Area box on a tracking point?

Tags: tracking, motion-capture

This has never been an issue until just now but consulting the official documentation it appears that there should be a search box which is distinct from the pattern area.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/movie_clip/tracking/clip/marker.html

Only... I don't seem to have it. I can see, rotate, deform etc. the ***pattern*** and I can ***resize*** the search area but there's no box to see the defined search area.

I've got some fairly fiddly tracking to do and to save time, I figured there's no point having huge search areas around each pattern, but the patterns are varied and organic in nature...

Maybe I've missed something but none of the videos I've caught seem to have it either. Did they removed this or is it disabled somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The visualization of the search area can be enabled in the *Clip Display* panel in the section *Marker Display*. Enable the checkbox named *Search* to show the search area. Alternatively you can also select a tracker and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

[image: Show search area]

The properties for the search area can be found in the *Track* tab on the *Marker* panel.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Well d'uh! I would be remiss of me not to say thanks (but I understand if a mod wants to remove this).

Comment: @MarcDraco You're welcome! If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: I got thousands of trackers, how do I show the search area

Comment: even if I select a marker and press ALT+S no search area is showing up

Comment: @Phil I just checked in Blender 3.1.2 and this works exactly as described above. The settings are also located in the same place. If this does not answer your question, then please post a new one and include screenshots of the entire user interface and where you expect to find the settings, but they do not appear.

Comment: no matter what, no search box appear, I even tried to check the user prefs/inputs but cannot find anything relevant